# R - Generate pairs of random variables that sum between 0 and 1

Tags: r, random

I need to generate 2 random variables from Uniform distribtuion. But I need to do it in such a way that `var1+var2<=1` and I need to make 10000 of them.
This is what I have done so far:

```
library(dplyr)
alpha <- 2
beta <- 4          
y1 <- runif(10000,0,1)^(1/alpha)
y2 <- runif(10000,0,1)^(1/beta)

 data.frame(y1,y2 ) %>% 
 filter(y1+y2<=1) %>% # check that y1+y1 <=1
NROW()
```

When I run this, I get back only 656 rows. I expect that, given that I filtered out so many variables. But is there a way to generate 10000 of such combinations without doing a `for loop`?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what distribution you want to sample the random variables from?

Comment: Im trying to sample from Uniform distribution but then convert it into Beta distribution using `If y1+y2<=1 then X=y1/(y1+y2)`

Comment: you could just divide y1 (=runif(1000)), and y2 by 2 but this will limit the range of each to 0,0.5, which I suspect is not what you want

Answer (score 1):

You can think of first generating `y1`. Now, for each `y1` generate `y2` using `mapply` in such a way that condition `y1+y2<=1` is met.

An example to generate `10` such values:

```
set.seed(1)
y1 <- runif(10,0,1)^(1/alpha)
df <- data.frame(y1) 

# max argument for for runif for each value y1 to generate value for y2
df$y2 <- mapply(function(x)runif(1, 0, (1-x)^beta)^(1/beta), df$y1)

# Just for validation purpose
df$sum <- rowSums(df)

#           y1         y2       sum
# 1  0.5152753 0.32654913 0.8418245
# 2  0.6100196 0.25279232 0.8628119
# 3  0.7568708 0.22135023 0.9782210
# 4  0.9529994 0.03700120 0.9900006
# 5  0.4490901 0.51603705 0.9651272
# 6  0.9478342 0.04381548 0.9916497
# 7  0.9719441 0.02582249 0.9977666
# 8  0.8128947 0.18672554 0.9996202
# 9  0.7931671 0.16239609 0.9555632
# 10 0.2485684 0.70559725 0.9541657
```

Answer (score 0):

```
y1 <- runif(10000, 0, .25)^(1/2)  # Max will be .5
y2 <- runif(10000, 0, .0625)^(1/4) # Max will be .5
```

Comment: This will work, but I'm need to find out if each random variable needs to be samples from U(0,1) distribution. This is for a Probabilities problem from a course. I need to convert this into Beta distribution afterwards using `If y1+y2<=1 then X=y1/(y1+y2)`

Comment: You should not post a question that incompletely describes the problem.